# CrittercismIOS conflict with MvvmCross

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, crittercism, xamarin-component

I'm integrating crash reporting via CrittercismIOS and i have used component on Xamarin Component store

https://components.xamarin.com/view/crittercism

but app crash with error reported.

```
2015-11-25 10:49:50.621 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical: Stacktrace:

2015-11-25 10:49:50.621 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2015-11-25 10:49:50.621 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (object,object[]) [0x00016] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2356/9ce9e8b9/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:650
2015-11-25 10:49:50.621 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (bool) [0x000ca] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2356/9ce9e8b9/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:113
2015-11-25 10:49:50.622 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (bool,bool,bool,System.Threading.StackCrawlMark&) [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2356/9ce9e8b9/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:87
2015-11-25 10:49:50.622 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (bool,bool,bool,System.Threading.StackCrawlMark&) [0x0002a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2356/9ce9e8b9/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:5734
2015-11-25 10:49:50.622 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type,bool) [0x00040] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2356/9ce9e8b9/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:214
2015-11-25 10:49:50.622 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2356/9ce9e8b9/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:147
2015-11-25 10:49:50.622 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxTouchViewsContainer.CreateViewOfType (System.Type,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest) <IL 0x00077, 0x002fb>
2015-11-25 10:49:50.622 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxTouchViewsContainer.CreateView (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest) <IL 0x0003e, 0x0018f>
2015-11-25 10:49:50.623 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxCanCreateTouchViewExtensionMethods.CreateViewControllerFor (Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.IMvxCanCreateTouchView,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest) <IL 0x00007, 0x0004a>
2015-11-25 10:49:50.623 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.Presenters.MvxTouchViewPresenter.Show (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest) <IL 0x00003, 0x00037>
2015-11-25 10:49:50.623 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxTouchViewDispatcher/<>c__DisplayClass4.<ShowViewModel>b__3 () <IL 0x00028, 0x00090>
2015-11-25 10:49:50.623 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxTouchUIThreadDispatcher.RequestMainThreadAction (System.Action) <IL 0x00028, 0x000e8>
2015-11-25 10:49:50.623 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Touch.Views.MvxTouchViewDispatcher.ShowViewModel (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest) <IL 0x00024, 0x0015b>
2015-11-25 10:49:50.623 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModelImpl (System.Type,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxRequestedBy) <IL 0x00030, 0x00145>
2015-11-25 10:49:50.623 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel (System.Type,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxRequestedBy) <IL 0x00006, 0x0004f>
2015-11-25 10:49:50.624 MyApp[40227:2065265] critical:   at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxNavigatingObject.ShowViewModel<T_REF> (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.IMvxBundle,Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxRequestedBy) <IL 0x0000e, 0x0005b>
```

MvvmCross version is 3.5.1 and Crittercism 2.4 on Xamarin Component Store.

If i remove in FinishedLaunching this code

```
CrittercismIOS.Crittercism.Init("00ac4950703d418c9cef9b7818cc307300444503");
```

App works fine (it works fine also with Xamarin.Insight, but it is not possible to use both dll).

Comment: I have the same thing with Crittercism and iOS.

Comment: Could you post MonoMethod.cs:650 for reference?

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs#L650

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 2.5 resolve this issue

https://components.xamarin.com/view/crittercism

Answer (score -1):

For MvvmCross, you should put the Crittercism initialization in your `Setup.cs` class.

```
public Setup(Context applicationContext) : base(applicationContext)
{
    Crittercism.Init (applicationContext, "YOUR APP ID GOES HERE");
}
```

The setup instructions provided in the Crittercism Xamarin documentation make the assumption that you're putting the code in a class that inherits from an Android Activity.  With MvvmCross, this does not apply.  You need to put the initialization in your Setup method instead as shown above.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce with any of the MvvmCross samples (https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples).  I tried on the ValueConversion app and was not able to reproduce on iOS.  I did get a crash on Android, but was due to incomplete integration instructions.